# Need to get submission_id of elementor form to add in reference and content of the mail

Tags: wordpress, elementor, submission

I use the elementor pro form for my contact form. I want to add the submission_id to the mail. I want to display the id in the reference header and in the body of the mail. Like a ticket-System.

EXP: New Mail from xxx - ID: 4566334

I tried to use the following code to add a new shortcode, that gives back the submission_id, but ist not working. Is empty and dont have a value:

```
add_shortcode( 'submission_id', 'get_submission_id' );

function get_submission_id() {
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['form_id'] ) || ! isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ) {
    return '';
  }

  $form_id = intval( $_POST['form_id'] );
  $nonce_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_wpnonce'] );

  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce_value, 'elementor-pro-form-' . $form_id ) ) {
    return '';
  }

  $submission_data = ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Form::get_instance( $form_id )->get_submission_data();
  if ( ! $submission_data || ! isset( $submission_data['_id'] ) ) {
    return '';
  }

  return $submission_data['_id'];
}
```

Any other way to add the submission id from elementor form to the mails?

I tried different plugins, but i dont want to pay for a plugin, just to get the id.

Also tried to add my own shortcode the the function.php, but i doesnt give back a value.

UPDATE: It seems that this part doesnt work

```
if ( ! isset( $_POST['form_id'] ) || ! isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ) {
    return 'Error 01';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

My unique id is a code from date and time. I added a hidden text field to the form, then in the advanced tab I selected dynamic data, page, current time.
You can set any date/time format along with any character/word etc..

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I thought about that and tried it out. Yer it is a simple solution, but not very safe, because technically you can generate the same ID, even if its very unlikely.

The second thing is, that the id is not continuous.

But as long as elementor don't have a function / shortcode for a submission_Id iam foreced to use that solution.